# What is the meaning of a proprietary API in an open source application such as MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, open-source

In https://www.mongodb.com/building-large-scale-applications-internet-things-bosch-transcript, they explain

> Technically, basically, we're using our proprietary device information
>   model performance and actually, I didn't put source code on this,
>   because it's going to be a long ugly hairy piece of XML. But
>   eventually, this is mapped to a MongoDB JSON format.

In many places on the Internet, they interpret this as meaning that MongoDB uses a proprietary API. For example,in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/nosqldb/documentation/nosql-vs-mongodb-1961723.pdf, they wrote:

> The focus of MongoDB is on developer friendliness and it has a rich
>   set of proprietary  API’s layered on top of a secondary index support
>   for the JSON value type.

IMHO, an open API is the most important part of any open source application. I don't even understand how an application could be open source and use a proprietary API, for example, reserved to commercial partners. I am just starting with MongoDB, don't know yet if the open JSON format is the complete API, but this would mean that the API is open, not proprietary. Otherwise, is the proprietary part of this API reserved to commercial partners?  Anyway, my question is what is meant by a proprietary API in an open source application such as MongoDB? What are the implications of this for someone that cares about Open source?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. Did you find the answer anywhere else?